# Why is entity framework trying to find these non-existant columns?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

```
public partial class User {

         public int Id { get; set; }

         public Nullable<int> InvoiceAddress_Id { get; set; }

         public Nullable<int> MailAddress_Id { get; set; }


         public virtual Address Address { get; set; }

         public virtual Address Address1 { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to retrieve user using Linq and Entity framework, I get;

```
Invalid column name 'Address_Id1'.
Invalid column name 'Address1_Id1'.
Invalid column name 'Address_Id'.
Invalid column name 'Address_Id1'.
```

I have no idea why it's coming up like that and doing search for any of these columns in the solution gives nothing! I have a feeling it has something to do with foreign keys.

```
 public partial class Address
{
    public Address()
    {
        this.User = new HashSet<User>();
        this.User1 = new HashSet<User>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Customer> User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Customer> User1 { get; set; }

}
```

Here is how I'm using entity framework:

```
CustomDbContext db = new CustomDbContext ();
var user =  db.User.First(a => a.Id != 0);
```

Here's the updated code:

```
public partial class User
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Nullable<int> InvoiceAddress_Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> MailAddress_Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Address InvoiceAddress_ { get; set; }
    public virtual Address MailAddress_ { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the error:

```
Invalid column name 'Address_Id'.
Invalid column name 'Address_Id1'.
```

Comment: Are the bogus columns in your EDMX?

Comment: Are you using code first or database first. What version of EF are you using. Can you also supply the class Address and the call you are making to EF.

Comment: I assume you have added and then later tried to remove these columns from the designer - they are probably still hanging around somewhere. Check the XML for the EDMX file.

Comment: @James Doing a search for these terms across the solution gives nothing.

Comment: @RobertHarvey No. Not in the EDMX diagram.

Comment: Latest version of EF?  Duplicate partial classes?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Runtime version: v4.0.30319. Version: 6.0.0.0.  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.0" targetFramework="net40" />

Comment: I couldn't find any duplicate classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is quite clear: nor your code (attributes, fluent API), neither the EF conventions are configuring the FKs.

If you want to use conventions, you have to adjust the names of the properties and the foreign keys, so that they can be configured. Where you have:

```
public Nullable<int> InvoiceAddress_Id { get; set; }
public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
```

You should have:

```
public Nullable<int> InvoiceAddressId { get; set; }
public virtual Address InvoiceAddress { get; set; }
```

Note that the FK name is the navigation property name + `"Id"`

Other option is to implement `OnModelCreating` of your DbContext and configure the FKs using the fluent API:

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOptional(u => u.Address)
            .WithMany();
            .HasForeingKey(a => a.InvoiceAddres_Id);
    }
```

Or use the `[ForeignKey("")]` attribute:

> The annotation may be placed on the foreign key property and specify the associated navigation property name, or placed on a navigation property and specify the associated foreign key name

I.e.

```
[ForeignKey("Address")]
public Nullable<int> InvoiceAddress_Id { get; set; }
```

or

```
[ForeignKey("InvoiceAddress_Id")]
public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
```

Comment: I followed your first suggestion and that helped get rid of first two errors, but the second two errors still persist. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you changed both navigation properties and both foreing key fields? (I only did for one of the fields, to show you how to do it, but must be done for both) If you've changed both, you should show how your code looks like now, and what are the errors.

Comment: I think it's because User and User1 are missing configuration / conventions. Try solving this problem. If you don't need to find which users are related to an adress you can even remove this properties.

Comment: I removed the properties, but the problem persisted. I think it wants primary key of address table to be address_id instead of just id. That maybe explains why it's trying to find Address_Id and Address_Id1. I'll keep debugging this, but let me know if you have any further ideas.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand very well how your model looks like. Can you capture a picture of how your model should look like? In hte meantime, install Entity Framework Powertools in Visual Studio, right click on the file containing the DbContext class, and choose "View EDM model (read-only)" (or something like that). There you'll see a drwaing of the schema that EF is inferring from your code. Try to use fleunt api or attributes to fine-tune it, instead of depending on conventions.